# Do something based on current time (minutes)

Tags: python

I am trying to exec my code depending on the current time...
for example, if minutes are (05, 10, 15, 20, 25,30) do something...

```
t = time.localtime()
current_time = time.strftime("%M", t)

my_list = [05, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55]

if current_time == my_list:
    print("its time to do something")
```

I also tried to do it with module but it didn't work.

```
t = time.localtime()
current_time = time.strftime("%M", t)

if current_time % 5:
    print("its time to do something")
```

Comment: hi, if you're trying to do something with and schedule, probably `schedule` library will help you better. take a look at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-schedule-library/ for syntax guidance (`schedule.every(5).minutes.do(something)`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first example has a couple of mismatched data types. Since `time.strftime` returns a `str` (string) you cannot compare it with `int` (integers) that are present in `my_list`. Moreover, you try to compare `current_time` (which is a string) to an entire `list`. So, the first example can be fixed like this:

```
import time
t = time.localtime()
current_time = time.strftime("%M", t)    # here still a string
current_time = int(current_time)         # converted to integer

my_list = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55]    # note these are all integers, so 05 is just 5

if current_time in my_list:    # note operator "in"
    print("its time to do something")
```

I personally like better the modulo operation, as it is more concise. However you need to remember that `0` evaluates to `False`, hence your statement would not trigger when you desire. So, you can negate the statement, with an `if not` but for readability, I would just explicitly put out the comparison with the desired value of `0`:

```
import time
t = time.localtime()
current_time = time.strftime("%M", t)    # here still a string
current_time = int(current_time)         # converted to integer

if current_time % 5 == 0:                # note the explicit comparison with 0
    print("its time to do something")
```

And of course, instead of doing the whole `time.strftime` and `int` conversion, you could just use the more compact `tm_min`:

```
import time
current_time = time.localtime()

if current_time.tm_min % 5 == 0:                # note the explicit comparison with 0
    print("its time to do something")
```

Comment: Wow!! thanks a lot for the info!!! i appreciate that!

Answer (score 0):

`time.strftime("%M", t)` returns a str object. Your list consists of integer. Use int() on your current time to change it into integer. It matches the type of list now and you can perform arithmetic expressions on them.

I've added a small script to explain it further :

```
import time
t= time.localtime()
current_time=time.strftime("%M",t)

print("current_time is of type",type(current_time))

current_time=int(current_time)

if(current_time % current_time)==0:
    print('It is integer and works now')
```

The output is:

```
 current_time is of type <class 'str'> 
 It is integer and works now
```

Answer (score 0):

You are very close. Just use existed methods inside your time object to get minutes like this.

```
import time
now = time.localtime()
current_time = now.tm_min
# or tm_year, tm_mon, tm_mday, tm_hour, tm_min, tm_sec, ...

if current_time % 5:
    print("its time to do something")
```